# Upload and Download a file to/From a nginx fileserver using curl command

Tags: python, nginx, curl, fileserver

I am trying to upload/download a file to/form a nginx fileserver. IT Admins provided my a public url such as for example https://file,storage.production/ and form a client computer I am trying to upload/download files using a curl command but i have no idea on how to do this. Any ideas?

Also, some Python code snippet would be highly appreciated.